# Can the WorkManager's behavior after reboots be customized?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am exploring the option of using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) for some of my usecases where a work item needs to be executed after a scheduled delay. Based on experimentation, I noticed this behavior

1. WorkManager gracefully handles scheduling of work items and respects the configured delay even after a reboot as long as the delay has not elapsed when the device is shutdown.
2. If the delay for certain work items has elapsed when the device is in shutdown state, WorkManager eventually acts on all such work items at the same time (delay is no longer respected) once the device is rebooted.

Is what I am observing the expected behavior? If so ,
Is there a way to customize the behavior in 2 above? Basically, I am asking if the same delay can be respected after reboot. Potentially , this could be done with saving some state so that the work items that have elapsed delay can be differentiated, but wanted to check if WorkManager itself provides interfaces to customize this behavior.

For reference, Here's how I am initializing the WorkManager and scheduling work after a set delay (5 minutes in this example)

```
OneTimeWorkRequest workItem =
                new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWork.class)
                .setInitialDelay(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

WorkManager.getInstance()
                .beginUniqueWork(<some_id>,
                ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                workItem)
                .enqueue();
```

Comment: The delay is in real time, not "the device is turned on" time so it sounds like it is working exactly as expected.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. 
But the intention was to add delay from the time a work request is scheduled. And different workrequests could have different delays. 

However, When a device reboots, WorkManager apparently applies same policy to all the queued requests whose delay has elapsed and acts on all of them at the same time (not respecting the initial policy). This was bit of a surprize as I couldn't find this behavior documented anywhere.

Comment: The initial delay is certainly respected. You're just saying if you set an initial delay of 5 minutes and another for 10 minutes that if your device is off for 15 minutes both fire simultaneously because more than 5 and 10 minutes have passed in real life? If you're trying to make a dependency between when one work request runs and another, is there a reason you aren't just scheduling the second work from the first work?

Comment: In my case, it's not necessarily an ordering problem where events have to trigger one after other (hence a depedency). Rather, I want to prevent the bursty event handling (all at once) which is why I wanted scheduled work requests with possibly random delays in first place

Comment: WorkManager already has behavior for limiting the amount of concurrent work, which can be further customized by providing your own Executor (i.e., one with a fixed pool) via [custom configuration](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration). What makes you think that this 'bursty' work is a problem?

Comment: >> What makes you think that this 'bursty' work is a problem?
For instance, each work request could be an API call which has some throttling limits set. Bursty traffic could be a problem in this case.

Answer (score 1):

WorkManager doesn't provide such facility. The only info you can get from a Worker are its state (ENQUEUED, RUNNING, SUCCEEDED, FAILED, BLOCKED, CANCELLED), runAttemptCount and output.
You will need to implement it by yourself. Save in SharedPreferences the time when your worker ends. And check this time when the device reboot and eventually re-enqueue your worker with ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE

Comment: Thanks. That's definitely an option. But the same state (time when work is scheduled atleast) is stored and managed by WorkManager and managing this ourselves sounds like redundant effort. 

If that state (time when the work item was scheduled and time when it's supposed to be picked up approx) is exposed by the Work item (are they in some manner?) , that would also  make sense.

Comment: You're right it's redundant but there is no easy API to retrieve such state. WorkManager manages all the worker states in a room database in your app, you might probably be able to read it, but it's not common to do this.